# PHP/SSH: How to output (echo) ssh result if they content multiple page?

Tags: php, ssh, console, output, huawei-mobile-services

I am try connect by SSH to device (in my case Huawei switch), execute command and print result on web page.
If my $ssh_input equal like 'display arp | i 10.100.1.1' i have next result in terminal and same result on web page - all work fine.

[output one page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ApOL.png)

But when I try do $ssh_input equal like 'display arp | i 10.100' - result became with multiple page in terminal and i can press 'Space' next page.

[output multiple page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo44r.png)

But on web page this case result infinite load of page because, as I understand, code don't complete

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($ip, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'login', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $ssh_input);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream( $stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO );
echo "<pre>";
echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
echo "</pre>";
```

How I can modify my code for output that case with multiple page?

Comment: So, I am stiil need help ..)

Comment: And still no answer (